# Want to create a horizontal line in html with three colors

Tags: html, css

Guys I want to create a horizontal line with three different color.For example first 30% of the line will have gray color , other 30% of the line will have red color and last 40% of the line will have black color. Is it possible to create a horizontal line in html with these colors.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it's possible, you've got the logic to do it, try something yourself ;)

Answer (score 14):

You can use gradient for this:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #adadad 0%, #adadad 30%, #36d321 30%, #36d321 60%, #ff0202 60%, #ff0202 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#adadad), color-stop(30%,#adadad), color-stop(30%,#36d321), color-stop(60%,#36d321), color-stop(60%,#ff0202), color-stop(100%,#ff0202));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #adadad 0%,#adadad 30%,#36d321 30%,#36d321 60%,#ff0202 60%,#ff0202 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #adadad 0%,#adadad 30%,#36d321 30%,#36d321 60%,#ff0202 60%,#ff0202 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #adadad 0%,#adadad 30%,#36d321 30%,#36d321 60%,#ff0202 60%,#ff0202 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #adadad 0%,#adadad 30%,#36d321 30%,#36d321 60%,#ff0202 60%,#ff0202 100%);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqrtgjvm/)

Comment: This is probably "the" correct answer in a way - no pseudo-elements, purely styling the colour of the line. Just a shame about the unwieldy syntax and need for vendor-prefixing, which of course isn't your fault :)

Comment: I like this solution too. As CupawnTae says, the vendor prefixes make the solution look a little messy, but any css pre-processor such as SASS or LESS will make quick, tidy work of this.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a CSS solution with a single HTML element

HTML:

```
<div class="neapolitan"/>
```

CSS:

```
.neapolitan {
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    height:1px;
}
.neapolitan:before {
    content:'';
    background:gray;
    width:30%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.neapolitan:after {
    content:'';
    background:black;
    width:40%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o95cype0/

Comment: @web-tiki I'd rather use `top:0; bottom: 0;` to stretch the height of absolutely positioned pseudo-elements: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/dr0cbu30/1/

Comment: @HashemQolami good idea. You could also use `top:0; height: 100%;` of course

Comment: @HashemQolami yes, or `height:100%` to make line thikness customisation easier. http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/dr0cbu30/2/

Comment: @web-tiki jinx! I've edited my answer to use height:100%. I decided to leave the rest the same as I think it's very slightly quicker at a glance to see how it's working without having to mentally merge the CSS blocks, but in real life yes, I agree with your simplification.

Answer (score 2):

Align 3 div inside one, like this:

```
<div id="parent" style="float:left">
  <div stle="float:left; background:yellow; width:30%" />
  <div stle="float:left; background:orange; width:30%" />
  <div stle="float:left; background:grey; width:60%" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

yes got the answer, Created three different line with three different colors , each line with percentage of 30%,30% and 40% . Then showed it as a single line.

Comment: Exactly that, glad you got it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code also:

```
<style>
    .line
    {
        height:1px;
        width:100%;
        display:table;
    }
    .line .gray
    {
        background:gray;
        width:30%;
        height:100%;
        display:table-cell;
    }
    .line .red
    {
        background:red;
        width:30%;
        height:100%;
        display:table-cell;
    }
    .line .black
    {
        background:black;
        width:40%;
        height:100%;
        display:table-cell;
    }
</style>

<div class="line">
    <div class="gray"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/michaelvandeweerd/ycekqfpn/) of a possible solution to your question. It's simply a `div` that contains other `div`s that all have their own colour and width. You can easily customise it by changing the CSS. I hope this helps, good luck!

HTML:

```
<div id="line">
    <div id="gray"></div>
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="black"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#line {
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
}

div#line > div {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

div#gray {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: gray;
}

div#red {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: red;
}

div#black {
    width: 40%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: JSFiddle is great to have, but please include the actual code in your answer as well - the answer should stand on its own without the external link.